# JQgrid json date format for dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I have a date like

`Apr  8 2014  2:45PM` in my table

Now I need to convert it to `dd/mm/yyyy` using jqgrid format

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Can you explain a little bit more what you tried? Thx!

Comment: I have used the given solution but it looks like it will work with date type field and in my database it contains max varchar field so I am not able to get what condition I need to use :(.

Comment: @user3513973 you should convert your data to date type first. My answer was given in the idea that you have a date, as you specified in your question.

Comment: @user3513973 if you need help with the conversion, please specify what technology you are using server-side (backend), be it PHP, .NET, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `formatter` property to your field:

```
formatter : {
     date : {
       monthNames: [
         "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
         "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
       ],
       AmPm : ["am","pm","AM","PM"],
       srcformat: 'm-d-Y',
       newformat: 'd/m/Y',
       parseRe: /[Tt\\\/:_;.,\t\s-]/,
       masks : {
         ISO8601Long:"Y-m-d H:i:s",
         ISO8601Short:"Y-m-d",
         ShortDate: "n/j/Y",
         LongDate: "l, F d, Y",
         FullDateTime: "l, F d, Y g:i:s A",
         MonthDay: "F d",
         ShortTime: "g:i A",
         LongTime: "g:i:s A",
         SortableDateTime: "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s",
         UniversalSortableDateTime: "Y-m-d H:i:sO",
         YearMonth: "F, Y"
       },
```

You will be most interested in these two elements:

```
 srcformat: 'm-d-Y',
 newformat: 'dd/mm/YYYY',
```

Learn more from the **[jqgrid formatter documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter)**.

I hope this helps, cheers.